# zsh script to encode full file path

Tags: url, zsh

I want to be able to encode a path for use as a url i.e change spaces to %20. I found this function which does the encoding:

```
urlencode() {
   setopt localoptions extendedglob
   input=( ${(s::)1} )
   print ${(j::)input/(#b)([^A-Za-z0-9_.\!~*\'\(\)-    ])/%${(l:2::0:)$(([##16]#match))}}
}
```

and want to be able to pass the results of this:

```
print -l $PWD/* | tail -1
```

to the function.i.e get the last full path in the file list and encode it.

I thought that something like this:

```
print -l $PWD/* | tail -1 | urlencode
```

or

```
print -l $PWD/* | tail -1 > urlencode
```

would work but they don't.

Does anyone know how to accomplish it?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get your input from `stdin` rather than from the first argument.

Here is one way to adapt the function to do this

```
urlencode() {
   setopt localoptions extendedglob
   stdin=`while read line; do echo $line ;done`
   input=( ${(s::)stdin} )
   print ${(j::)input/(#b)([^A-Za-z0-9_.\!~*\'\(\)-    ])/%${(l:2::0:)$(([##16]#match))}}
}
```

I tested it on my terminal, it works

Comment: This didn't work for me: (1) I think the whitespace got messed up when you copied and pasted, and (2) it encodes forwards slashes (path separators). Here's what worked for me `print ${(j::)input/(#b)([^A-Za-z0-9_.\!~*\'\(\)-\/])/%${(l:2::0:)$(([##16]#match))}}`